# How to Pass Form Group Data to Submit Button in Another Component (Angular 7)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7

I'm having issues passing my form group data to the saveDialog() function which updates the form data on a submit button.

How would I do this in Angular 7? I'm trying to have all my components for each form group seperated, and submitted/updated together using one button?

**modify-view-action.component.html**

```
      <form [formGroup]="modifyActionForm" (ngSubmit)="saveDialog()">
    <div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="25px">
      <div class="column1" fxLayout="column">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
          <input matInput>
          <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Keyword</mat-label>
          <input matInput>
          <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
          <input matInput>
          <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Icon</mat-label>
          <input matInput>
          <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Priority</mat-label>
          <input matInput>
          <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </form>
```

**modify-view-action.component.ts**

```
export class ModifyViewActionComponent implements OnInit {
  modifyActionForm: FormGroup;
  dbrAction: any;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initData();
  }

  initData() {
    this.dbrAction = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DbrAction'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Try this https://therichpost.com/how-to-pass-data-from-one-component-to-another-component-in-angular-9/

Comment: Where is the `FormGroup` data? Where is `modifyActionForm` initialized?

Comment: Please create a stackblitz to reproduce the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First in order to get data from a **FormGroup** you need to add **formControlName** on each input you want data from. Like that :

```
 <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="name">
      <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
 </mat-form-field>
```

You also need to declare in your .ts file, the **FormGroup** with each controllers. Like that :

```
modifyActionForm = new FormGroup({
  name : new FormControl(),
  keyword: new FormControl(),
  description: new FormControl(),
  // And that ⬆ for each input in your form
})
```

In order to get the data from this **FormGroup** you need to do this :

```
this.modifyActionForm.value
```

You will get an Object with your inputs' data.

Your question is not quite clear but if you want to pass data like for example your FormGroup from a component to another one, many techniques exist.

I recommend you to read this great article from **Jeff Delaney** explaining the different way to sharing Data between Angular Components ([Fireship.io - Sharing Data between Angular Components](https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)) and this one [Fireship.io - Angular Reactive Forms Basics Guide](https://fireship.io/lessons/basics-reactive-forms-in-angular/) explaining how works reactive forms and how to use them.

Good day !